# Divergences in the Klein Gordon equation?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, klein-gordon-equation

### Question

Where are the UV and Infrared divergences present in the Klein Gordon equation:

$$ \hat E^2 |\psi> = (\hat p^2 + m^2)|\psi> $$

Before diagonalizing the operators (substituting with creating and annihilation operators)?